# Inheritance with Fluent NHibernate produces double results

Tags: nhibernate, fluent

I have the following scenario:

```
public class Login
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
}

public class User : Login
{
    public IList<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

If I have two maps (`ClassMap<Login>` and `ClassMap<User>`), all queries returns double results - one per maps I'd guess.

Is it possible to avoid this? I don't have a discriminator value. There are a lot more properties on the user, so I'd like to be able to just get a sub set of these via the login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since User extends Login, querying Login will, by default, return User instances too.

To avoid this, `polymorphism="explicit"` must be used in the XML mappings.

For Fluent mappings, use `Polymorphism.Explicit()`.

Comment: It is supported by fluent nhibernate.

Comment: Please tell me the corresponding method so I add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps specifying different data tables for the two entities `Login` and `User` might do the trick, so you would have to explicitely query either the `Login` or `User` depending on your needs. Otherwise, Diego Mijelshon's answer sounds pretty good!